# python *args list of positional parameters

Tags: python, arguments, positional-argument

I have a function that takes as input `*args`:

```
def foo(*args): 
    for a in args:
        print(a)
```

This works as intended

```
> foo('a', 'b')
> a
> b
```

I am faced with a situation where I don't know how many args are going to be passed (which is the whole point of `args`), but I don't know how to create a "list of positional arguments" to be passed to the function.

Part of the challenge is to appropriately phrase the question..

Let me try with an example: the function may be called as `foo('a')` or it may be called as `foo('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')` but I don't know because this function is being called by another class that creates the list of unknown number of parameters.

Essentially I want to create a variable containing the parameters like so:

```
positional_arguments = ('a','b','c')
```

so that the function can be called like `foo(positional_arguments)`.

This however does not work as it does not correctly unpack `positional_arguments`:

```
> foo(positional_parameters)
> ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

but what I want is

```
> foo(positional_parameters)
> a
> b
> c
```

Comment: `foo(*positional_parameters)`? This isn't a problem with the function, you're *passing* them wrongly.

Comment: I don't recall saying that the function had a 'problem', I was merely stating what I have tried and was asking how to do it properly.